# post an array to webpage

Tags: php, html

it has error because  $_POST['sub1'] can't be accessed 
is there any approach or solution to echo the value of $_POST['sub1']? or impossible? no way? even with another arrays?
i had question about my code nobody solved it! then I decide to tell it in simple way.

```
<html>
<form method="post">
<input type='submit' name='sub1' value='sub1'>
<?php
if(array_key_exists('sub1',$_POST))
{
echo"<input type='submit' name='sub2' value='sub2'>";
}
if(array_key_exists('sub2',$_POST))
{
echo $_POST['sub1'];
}
?>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: yes very specific! because when i post the sub1 it has just sub1 and when i post the sub2 it has sub2 the value of sub1 won't be maintain

Comment: I know Mark B is right but I want an answer YES or NO can I store the value or NO it is impossible

Comment: YES, of course it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what is wrong here.

When you submit the form the second time (for sub2) you are no longer posting the value of sub1 along with it, just sub2.

This should fix it:

```
<html>
<form method="post">
<input type='submit' name='sub1' value='sub1'>
<?php
if(array_key_exists('sub1',$_POST))
{
echo"<input type='hidden' name='sub1' value='" . htmlentities($_POST['sub1']) . "'>";
echo"<input type='submit' name='sub2' value='sub2'>";
}
if(array_key_exists('sub2',$_POST))
{
echo $_POST['sub1'];
}
?>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: WELL DONE GENIUS! thank YOU! you don't know that how much you helped me!

Answer (score 1):

You're using submit buttons. Only the button that you actually click will have its name/value pair sent to the server. When you click the `sub2` button, only `sub2=sub2` is sent, so `sub1` won't exist in the $_POST array.

---

followup:

$_POST is created for you by PHP based on what's sent from the browser. The way you've built your form makes it impossible for 'sub1' to exist when you click the 'sub2' button. In other words, you need to use the SAME `name=` for BOTH buttons, and change the `value=` as appropriate:

html:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="sub1" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="sub2" />
```

php:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   echo "You clicked the {$_POST['submit']} button";
}
```

Comment: I can't even store it in array then you are telling me it is impossible?

Comment: You are right,but I have many array_key_exists that i can't have the same name,however thank you for your attention Mark B